# How can I get Visual Studio 2017 to interactively debug this line?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I have the following code set up as a dummy example to illustrate what I found in my production code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool GreaterThan(int x, int y)
    {
        return x > y;
    }

    bool OperateOnTwoNumbers(int x, int y, Func<int, int, bool> func)
    {
        return func(x, y);
    }

    var twoGreaterThanOne = OperateOnTwoNumbers(2, 1, GreaterThan);

}
```

When I set a watch, or interatively debug with <kbd>Shift+F9</kbd>, on `OperateOnTwoNumbers(2, 1, GreaterThan)`, I get the following error.

> OperateOnTwoNumbers(2, 1, GreaterThan)    error CS0103: The name 'OperateOnTwoNumbers' does not exist in the current context

But the code itself runs fine, and after I step over the line, I can see the value assigned to the variable.

This has been replicated on more than one computer, with the production code and with this dummy example, so I don't think it's an environment issue.

Here is a recording of the issue, it can be viewed in full quality by clicking on the recording and viewing it at its direct address.

[image: recording of problem]

Any ideas?

Comment: This seems very strange. Have you done a clean/rebuild? Do you have circular references?

Comment: This particular example is on a completely fresh project I created just for testing the concept, what you see is the whole codebase, there are no other reference or such. I tried a rebuild to no avail.

Comment: Have you done a Release or Debug build? The method might have been optimized out?

Comment: In both places I witnessed this it was in debug configuration.

Comment: I don't doubt that you're seeing an issue here, but in both of my tests (locally, and [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9SlB2s)) it seems fine. Have you analysed the generated IL?

Comment: To clarify, John, the code works perfectly, and as mentioned once I step past that line the value is assigned just fine. I'm specifically referring to the interactive evaluation of the the expression `OperateOnTwoNumbers(2, 1, GreaterThan)`.

Comment: There must be something different between your code that is experiencing the issue and your sample above as we're unable to replicate the issue.

Comment: @phuzi When you highlight the expression and hit Shift+F9 it works okay for you? My code works okay, it's just this particular debugging peculiarity that's not working.

Comment: I'm also able to debug all the way into `GreaterThan` (VS 2017 Enterprise 15.6.6).

Comment: Huh, weird. I'm not on Enterprise, maybe it's that. I wonder if it's worth submitting a bug report.

Comment: @Geesh I'll check on VS2017 Community when I get home in about 40 minutes or so.

Comment: Sounds good. Thanks for your input, guys. I've added a recording to the original post. It's a bit potato quality when embedded but the full quality can be seen by clicking on it which takes you to the direct address.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that watch expression evaluator has not yet been updated to handle local functions (or, if it works in some versions of VS and doesn't in others - has not been updated in your specific version).

Local functions (like `GreaterThan` and `OperateOnTwoNumbers`) are just syntax sugar and really compiled into static functions with cryptic names:

```
[CompilerGenerated]
internal static bool <Main>g__OperateOnTwoNumbers|0_1(int x, int y, Func<int, int, bool> func)
{
  return func(x, y);
}
```

And call to them is then:

```
Program.<Main>g__OperateOnTwoNumbers|0_1(...);
```

So watch expression evaluator should realize that, but it doesn't and tries to call function with `OperateOnTwoNumbers` name (as you can see from compiler error message "The name 'OperateOnTwoNumbers' does not exist in the current context"), and there is really no such function.